# Get content of blocked site in php

Tags: php, proxy

I want to get the content of website using php.
But the site which I want to get content is blocked in my region.

```
<?php file_get_contents('http://wwww.blocked_site_in_region.com'); ?>
```

I want to get only `title, Heading` and some other data.
I know there is a way to use `proxy` but I do not want to use it.
Is there any other way to achive this.
Thanks...

Comment: If your server can not reach the site you have no other solution than to use a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

It is something about your network, not PHP itself. So you need to use proxy as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: what is best and fast method to use proxy in php. ?